# CMake error: Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, homebrew

I am trying to use uint512_t in a boost library located in:

> multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp

however, when I try to include my boost library through CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(BoostTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(BOOSTROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/include")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(BoostTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I receive the following error message when compiling:

```
error: unknown type name 'uint512_t'
```

I don't know what the problem is. I even included:

> "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"

Comment: is the compiler complaining that it can't find `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp`? You might also want to have a look at the preprocessed code to see if `uint512_t` is included (or rather, why it's not). In GCC/G++, this is done with the `-E` switch. To use that switch, do `g++ foo.cpp -E -o preprocessed.e`.

Comment: I'm using an IDE called Clion to do this, so I don't know how I would use `g++ foo.cpp -E -o preprocessed.e`. However, I know that main.cpp can find the file because it's not telling me it can't.

This is my first time trying to utilize boost through Clion, and I'm wondering if I'm not doing something correct in CMake.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you know what your compiler is? MSVC? clang? g++? EDIT : Try, in your CMakeLists.txt, to `message(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})`. By the way, you included `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` twice.

Comment: Also, just to make sure it isn't a problem with the cpp_int.hpp file itself, try to copy that header into your working directory and then just `#include "cpp_int.hpp"` instead of `#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>`. If your program still yields the same error, it means you're using the header wrong, or the header in itself is wrong. But if it compiles, at least the problem (mostly) trims down to the `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})` line of your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you for catching the duplicated code. And I added `message(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})` and now CMake produces `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/include`

Comment: Okay, and I copied the header file into my current working directory, and I still have the same error.

Comment: Did you re-run cmake? Also, look inside the header. Do you see the declaration of `uint512_t`? (BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow, haha)

Comment: (Thanks. Haha) So first off, let me say that I took out the duplicated code, and then I got an error saying `cannot find boost`. But when I add the code back in, I'm able to not only find boost, but I also can find the definition of `uint512_t`. Here is the line of code for it: `typedef number<cpp_int_backend<512, 512, unsigned_magnitude, unchecked, void> >   uint512_t;` EDIT: Scratch that first statement (I changed find_package to find_library, but now it's fixed)

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Comment: No. It still says error: `unknown type name 'uint512_t'`

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_int_ref.html), type `uint512_t` is defined in `boost::multiprecision` namespace. Have you refer to the type using this namespace?

Comment: EDIT: Scratch the initial comment, it works! I, again, have changed things, and just needed to add in `#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"` along with `using namespace boost::multiprecision;` Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren Please post an answer below that explains how you fixed the problem. Please note that you should post an answer and *not* edit the solution into the original question. You can then accept your own answer, so that if someone stumbles over this question in the future, they see right away how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping everything else the same in main.cpp, all that was needed was:

```
using namespace boost::multiprecision
```